# Return in case of Recursive call to a method

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a piece of code that I need insight on, I don't want to know the correct solution of the problem. I just want to know why is my concept failing.
So the function is to check if a binary tree is BST or not. I need to return 1 in case it is and 0 otherwise. My code is as below

```
int isBST(Node root) {
 if(root == null)
  return 1;
 if(root.left!=null) {
  if(root.left.data<root.data)
    isBST(root.left);
  else
   return 0; // line:a
 }
 if(root.right!=null) {
  if(root.right.data<root.data)
    isBST(root.right);
  else
   return 0;
 }
return 1;
}
```

For this piece, when i have a binary tree as follows:

```
5
 \
  7
 /
8
```

I expect it to reach 8 value and break at line:a but it return me 1 instead of 0. Now I know 0 gets returned to the parent calling method. But is it not terminating because I have made isBST call without capturing the return value? 
Please dont point out if there are anyother bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, your approach won't work. The way to test if a tree is a BST is to recursively check if the current node is greater than the maximum element of the left subtree, and smaller than the minimum element of the right subtree. Also, you're missing the returns in the recursive calls:

```
return isBST(root.left);
...
return isBST(root.right);
```

By the way, why are you returning `0` or `1` for this? use `false` or `true` instead, changing the return type to `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks. just needed that confirmation, I guess need to find how to break the recursive calls now. Also, I am not using boolean because its a question from a coding platform that want answer in integer format.

Comment: Also see my first paragraph, I'm afraid that you'll have to rewrite your method, in its current form it won't work.

Comment: If I recursively look for a case where the root doesn't lie between the left and the right child and return 0 as soon as that happens in any subtree and return 1 if it happens never, why would it fail for general case? This code might not work but the theory would also not??

Comment: It's pretty easy to build a tree that will make your code fail, and demonstrates why my approach is the correct one (hint: don't think in terms of the _immediate_ left-and-right children, go deeper). Spend some time thinking about it, I don't want to spoil the fun of discovery ;)

Comment: Got it. if the right child of a subtree is greater than root, it'll pass but it might also be greater then the top root. in that case it isnt a bst but my logic would not figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @SonaliGupta fantastic, I knew you'd figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the right data ist bigger than the current and return the value of the recursive call

```
if(root.right.data>root.data)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, kindly do not point out things that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: @SonaliGupta  aren't relevant? are you sure about that? when checking node `5` it will test `7 < 5` and since false, return zero - better not post wrong code...

Comment: Yes because my question was about the recursive function not returning 0 for the left child(trying to find out how recursive func work). The less or greater is just a typo/bst logic.

Comment: @SonaliGupta mostly we expect a [mcve]....the reproducible is important in that concept.. (the missing return could also just be a typo) and "*I expect it to reach 8 value*" which will not happen

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues:

- If (and only if) `isBST(root.left)` or `isBST(root.right)` is false, you need to return 0 (btw, why are you not using booleans?) immediately.
- The condition `root.right.data<root.data` should be inverted: `root.right.data>=root.data`.

So here's the modified code (keeping the `int` return type):

```
int isBST(Node root) {
 if(root == null)
  return 1;
 if(root.left!=null) {
  if(root.left.data<root.data) {
    if (isBST(root.left) == 0)
      return 0;
  } else
   return 0;
 }
 if(root.right!=null) {
  if(root.right.data>=root.data) {
    if (isBST(root.right) == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  } else
   return 0;
 }
return 1;
}
```